# Transfer file from windows machine to another windows machine via command line?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I need to be able to transfer a file to a remote windows box, OS of windows vista or higher. I am transferring this file from one windows machine to another windows machine. The target machine isn't guaranteed to have SSH, or anything, but I have its login credentials. Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have valid credentials, you can try

```
net use \\other.machine.com\C$ /u:DOMAIN\USER /PERSISTENT:YES
```

where:

```
other.machine.com - is the machine you're going to connect to
DOMAIN - domain name
USER - user name
C$ - disk 'C' on the machine (if you have administrator's rights) or any another share you're legal to connect to
```

It will ask you for the password then.

If connection was successful, you can then mount this share as a network disk. Then you can just do 'copy' from command line on that disk.

Sure, it is not guaranteed this will work - that machine can be behind a firewall or there may not be shared any resources. But anyway you can try. I think, it is simplest way to do what you want without installing any additional applications.